# PowerQuery Range within Range

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm trying to filter out values within a certain range of values in a large dataset.
I have a small excerpt of the values data here:

```
Chng.1      Chng.2      Length   Post   Index
117,200     117,400     200      bf     1
118,800     119,000     200      bf     2
118,939     118,949     10       bo     3
119,863     119,873     10       bo     4
120,400     121,200     800      bf     5
120,869     120,879     10       bf     6
121,400     121,600     200      bo     7
128,800     129,200     400      bo     8
129,065     129,075     10       bo     9
```

In this data set I would like for Index 6 and 9 to be filtered out as they are already contained within a range.

i.e. the chainage of Index 6 (120,869-120,879) is within the chainage of Index 5 (120,400-121,200) and they are both post "bf". The same goes with Index 9 which is within the range of Index 8 and share the post "bo".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically in your case (subsequent range is inside previous one) you may use this code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table"]}[Content],
    sort = Table.Sort(Source, List.Transform({"Post", "Chng.1", "Chng.2"}, each {_, 0})),
    group = Table.Group(sort, Table.ColumnNames(Source), {}, 0,
                       (a,b)=>Number.From(b[Post] <> a[Post] or b[Chng.1] >= a[Chng.2]))
in
    group
```

[image]

Otherwise (ranges are intersect) try this code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table"]}[Content],
    cols = {"Post", "Chng.1", "Chng.2"},
    sort = Table.Sort(Source, List.Transform(cols, each {_, 0})),
    group = Table.Group(sort, cols,
                       {{"Chng.1_new", each List.Min([Chng.1])}, 
                        {"Chng.2_new", each List.Max([Chng.2])}}, 0,
                       (a,b)=>Number.From(b[Post] <> a[Post] or b[Chng.1] >= a[Chng.2])),
    add = Table.AddColumn(group, "Length", each ([Chng.2_new] - [Chng.1_new])*1000), //multiplication by 1000 is optional, depends on your decimal separator
    remove = Table.RemoveColumns(add, List.Skip(cols))
in
    remove
```

Comment: As I read your code it doesn't distinguish between the post column? When I run your code, I end up with 6 rows, i.e. 3 rows are removed, but only row 6 and 9 should be removed.

Comment: Thanks! We're getting there, but the code seems to be "unstable", i.e. if I add another row with chainage 120500-120600 and post bo, it wont filter out the row with chainage 120869-120879 anymore. Is it correct that the code is dependent on the sorting then?

Comment: Yes, for such cases sorting is needed. Corrected.